Python to PPTX using python-pptx library
I am trying to update ppt using python. I have following set of code and need a help to solve following issue.

Value in table should be integer with comma seperator.
The columns should auto adjust as sometime figures are too big and it spill over to next row which doesn't solve the pupose of automation.
The graph and table overlap, is there a way to dynamically adjust them so that irrespective of number of rows in table, graph will always be below table and not overlaping.

from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Demo/Demo.pptx'
# Sample data
data = {
    'Column1': [1234.56789, 2345.67890, 3456.78901, 4567.89012, 5678.90123],
    'Column2': [9876.54321, 8765.43210, 7654.32109, 6543.21098, 5432.10987],
    'Column3': [3210.98765, 4321.09876, 5432.10987, 6543.21098, 7654.32109],
    'Column4': [7890.12345, 8901.23456, 9012.34567, 1234.56789, 2345.67890],
    'Column5': [4567.89012, 3456.78901, 2345.67890, 1234.56789, 9876.54321]
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a PowerPoint presentation
prs = Presentation()

# Add first slide with title
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[0])
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Analysis"

# Add a slide for data and graph
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])  # Layout for title and content

# Add title for the slide
title_shape = slide.shapes.title
title_shape.text = "Basic Summary"

# Add a table for the data
left = Inches(1)
top = Inches(1.5)
width = Inches(8)
height = Inches(4)

# Create a table with rows and columns
table = slide.shapes.add_table(6, 6, left, top, width, height).table

# Set column widths
table.columns[0].width = Inches(2)
table.columns[1].width = Inches(1.5)
table.columns[2].width = Inches(1.5)
table.columns[3].width = Inches(1.5)
table.columns[4].width = Inches(1.5)
table.columns[5].width = Inches(1.5)

# Set column titles
table.cell(0, 0).text = ' '
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    table.cell(0, i+1).text = col

# Populate the table with data
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), start=1):
    for j, value in enumerate(row[1:], start=1):
        table.cell(i, j).text = f'{value:.5f}'

# Plot the graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('X Label')
plt.ylabel('Y Label')
plt.title('Graph Title')

# Save the plot to a file
plt.savefig('graph.png')

# Add the graph to the slide
left = Inches(1)
top = Inches(5)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture('graph.png', left, top, width=Inches(8), height=Inches(3))

# Save the presentation
prs.save(path)

# Close the plot
plt.close()



Once I worked in a university. There, I wrote a python program to generate PDF of professor evaluation statistical results. The results was tables with fixed number of rows and variable number of columns (from 4 to 20 columns).
It was hard, if not impossible to generate good looking reports for all possible variations of the reports. So I created a OpenOffice.org Flat XML ODF Text Document (.fodt) as template for each variation as template. Then I selected appropriate template file based on number of columns and fill it and convert it to PDF using OpenOffice programmatically.
The results was very fine. So I suggest a similar solution here using LibreOffice Flat XML ODF Presentation (.fodp)
If you don't want to do this method, you must set font size of table based on its number of rows and columns. You must set margin of table cells to 0 and use minimal height to rows.

I would suggest using top and height attributes for the table object to compute the bottom of your table. Then set the graph position to top + height + pad where pad is the desired padding between the table and graph.
You may run into cases where your image is too large to fit on the slide. In that case you could scale your image based on the remaining room between the table's bottom and the bottom of the slide.
